# Как сделать импликацию?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
a = 9   #кол-во строк таблицы
b = 5   #кол-во столбцов таблицы

f = a
e = a
p = a
x = ''
y = ''
impl = ''  #переменная для хранения результата импликации
print('A:')
while a - 1 > 4:
    x = x + '0'
    a = a - 1
while a - 1 > 0:
    x = x + '1'
    a = a - 1
print(x) #переменная для хранения информации столбца A
print()

print('B:')
while f - 1 > 6:
    y = y + '0'
    f = f - 1
while f - 1 > 4:
    y = y + '1'
    f = f - 1
while f - 1 > 2:
    y = y + '0'
    f = f - 1
while f - 1 > 0:
    y = y + '1'
    f = f - 1
print(y)  #переменная для хранения информации столбца B

print()

print('A -> B:')   #начало импликации
while p > 0:
    for i in x:
        for j in y:
            if i == j:
                impl = impl + '1'
                p = p - 1
            elif i == '0' and j == '1':
                impl = impl + '1'
                p = p - 1
            elif i == '1' and j == '0':
                impl = impl + '0'
                p = p - 1
print(impl) #конец импликации
```

Не получается импликация. При выводе переменной, содержащей ее, выводится не понятно для меня что.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать(получить) и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Нужно сделать таблицу истинности по данной формуле:  F = (А→В)˄¬А.
И тут есть действие импликация (А→В). И я вот не знаю как его сделать. При выводе, результатом выводится: 1111111111111111111111111111111100110011001100110011001100110011, хотя не должно. И вот я не понимаю, где я сделал ошибку

Comment: Ничего не понял...

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/cwBpB9

```
print("A B A➛B")

for a in range(0, 2):
  for b in range(0, 2):
    print(a, " ", b, "  ", +(a<=b), sep="")
```

```
A B A➛B
0 0  1
0 1  1
1 0  0
1 1  1
```

Comment: `+(a<=b)` - прикольно, не видел такого варианта на питоне )  Но может всё же "явное лучше не явного" и `int(a<=b)`? )  Хотя красиво, конечно, надо запомнить )

Answer (score 0):

У меня не удалось найти ошибку в коде, но если нужно просто  решить задачу, то можно воспользоваться фрагментом ниже. Там правда задействованы функции, словари и срезы строк, однако в этом не очень сложно, зато очень важно разобраться. Если пишешь свой "мудрённый" код (по сути любой код, в частности если опираешься на самые базовые команды), то опиши алгоритм действий.

```
def binary(number):
    b = bin(number) # result is str
    ans = b[2:] # first 2 simbol is '0b'
return ans

a = binary(5)
b = binary(7)

A = a[::-1]  # перевернём строки, чтобы уравнять длины
B = b[::-1]  # строк простым оператором (+=) 

k = len(A) - len(B) # разница длин чисел в двоичной системе
while k != 0:
if k > 0:
    A += '0'
else:
    B += '0'
a = A[::-1] #возвращаем строки в исходный
b = B[::-1] # порядок

c = ' '
dimpl = { '00': '1', '01': '1', '11': '1', '10': '0' }
for i in range(len(a)):
    c += dimpl[ a[i]+b[i] ]
'''Все сценарии импликации указаны в словаре dimpl (dict - impl). Поочерёдно подставляем ему в качестве ключа склееные биты из наших бинарных чисел в формате строк, не боясь получить ошибку выхода за конец строки. В результате также получим строку'''
print('a =', a, 'b =', b, 'iplicatiom(a,b) =', c)
```